# How to properly implement Stripe to an AdonisJS project?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment, adonis.js

I know the question is pretty generic, but I'm currently developing a web app using the AdonisJS framework and I'm trying to implement the possibilty of buying things on this website with Stripe. To do so, I've looked up several different methods to properly include Stripe into this project, but none of them seemed to work for me. So I wanted to ask, if anyone has experience with that and could help me out with an optimal way to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there is a third party library specifically for using Stripe with Adonis if you have not tried that already. https://github.com/bitkidd/adonis-stripe

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you have tried already and what issues you ran in to?

Comment: Yeah I've already stumbled across the adonis-stripe package by mezzielabs and the one by bitkidd, but I wasn't quite sure what exactly to do with those to get the standard stripe checkout page working. Now I'm trying https://medium.com/@victor.valencia.rico/online-payments-with-stripe-and-adonisjs-8d9140aa8e72 and hope to get results. I'm just very clueless about this whole thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.